# Problems printing array of XML

Tags: php, xml

I have the following code that takes the "money" all my XML field but only 1 record and shows me this error:

Error:

```
 Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /var/www/client/lib/class/index.php on line 34

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): %PDF-1.4 in /var/www/client/lib/class/index.php on line 34

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ in /var/www/client/lib/class/index.php on line 34

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /var/www/client/lib/class/index.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/client/lib/class/index.php(34): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('%PDF-1.4?%?????...') #1 /var/www/client/lib/class/index.php(47): uuid->select() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/client/lib/class/index.php on line 34
```

My code:

```
$data = $this -> conect -> conexion();          
           $dbquery = $data -> prepare("SELECT * 
                                        FROM FILE 
                                        ORDER BY ID
                                      ");


                 $dbquery->execute();
       while($rows = $dbquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
              $string = $rows['BYTES'];
                $tuxml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
         echo $tuxml->attributes()->Moneda;
```

Comment: Please provide an example of `$string` before it goes into SimpleXMLElement

Comment: If you move without the loop prints me: "Mexican pesos"

Comment: So it's a text string, and you're trying to parse it as XML?

Comment: The problem is that whoever programmed this application put the XML in the database MySQL by bad mind. and he held out the currency of each XML

Answer (score 2):

### Analysis

Reading the exception information properly reveals the origin of the problem:

```
Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

**Conclusion:** You try to parse something that is no valid XML

```
SimpleXMLElement->__construct('%PDF-1.4?%?????...')
```

**Conclusion:** Looks like you are trying to parse a PDF file as indicated by the magic number "%PDF":

> **Magic number(s):**
> All PDF files start with the characters '%PDF-' using the PDF
> version number, e.g., '%PDF-1.4'.  These characters are in US-
> ASCII encoding.
>
> *(Source: RFC 3778, Page 9, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3778)*

### Resolutions

- Ensure your source contains only valid XML files
- Try to detect the mime type of the file and skip non XML files
- Add a surrounding try-catch block to handle files not parseable as XML

Comment: The XML SQL databases are in a type "LONGBLOB"